# Why is it showing enum, interface expecting errors?

Tags: java, interface, enums

THIS program is showing this errors asking interface in package concept...why is it so? can't i do package without using interfaces? i tried with that too..but still the same error is showing..what to do..pls help  please click on this link fr the screenshot [errors regaring interface and enum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjq8W.jpg)

```
package Car_package;

    public class Car {        
        public static int carnum;
        public static String carname;
        public static void display (int a, String car_name) {
            carnum = a;
            carname = car_name;
            System.out.println ("Car Number is: " +carnum);
            System.out.println ("Car Name is  : " +carname);
        }
    }

import Car_package.*;

public class CarImportPackage {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Car.display (777, "Ferrari");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you need to put `CarImportPackage` class into its own file.

Comment: can you pls explain ..i am not able to get the point

Comment: You complie `bmw.java` and `Car_package.java`, but your class name is `Car` or `CarImportPackage`. The file name and the class name must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

As says the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6), at most one public class can be declared in the same file.

So your class should look like this:

```
package Car_package;

public class Car {        
    public static int carnum;
    public static String carname;
    public static void display (int a, String car_name) {
        carnum = a;
        carname = car_name;
        System.out.println ("Car Number is: " +carnum);
        System.out.println ("Car Name is  : " +carname);
    }
}

/*import Car_package.*; DELETED: You don't need to import the 
class, as it is declared in the same file */

class CarImportPackage { //Remove public keyword
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Car.display (777, "Ferrari");
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would have served better as a comment than an answer. If you want to make it answer worthy, I would suggest you post an example set of code that would resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood java packaging. A java package is simply a folder containing classes.

Imagine you have this project. All source files are located under src directory.

```
src
├── a
│   ├── A.java
│   └── b
│       └── B.java
└── c
    └── C.java
```

The packages are `a`, `a.b` and `c`.
In order to import a class from **another** package, the `import` directive is written at the top of a file.

Now, if you want your code to work, then here is how your architecture should be:

```
src
├── CarImportPackage.java
└── Car_package
    └── Car.java
```

Now, you can run your project, and it will show the desired output.

Now, about conventions, Java package are written in lowercase letters, without special characters inside. So, you should rename `Car_package` in something else, like `car`.

Plus, you shouldn't use the `default` package (`CarImportPackage` is inside it at the moment).